# enabling asp.net compatibility mode

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, compatibility

I'm trying to build some simple REST services with WCF 3.5 and host them on IIS6 (yeah, old technologies). When I enable aspnet compatibility to get access to http context, browsing the .svc file returns the following error:

> "The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET
>   compatibility... add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to
>   the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or
>   'Required'."

That's what I did, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "foo"
    )]
    string foo();
}
```

Implementation:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed))] //or AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required
public class Service : IService
{
    public string foo(){
        return "hello world!";
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
        ...
    </system.serviceModel>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think it's `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />`